# PowerBI Preview cannot refresh workbook with Azure SQL datasource

Tags: excel, powerbi

I've been working on creating workbook and share them on PowerBI Preview service, and today I found that I couldn't schedule a refreshment on my workbook.

Inside this workbook, I connect with my data source(Azure SQL database) by using the Excel PowerQuery. At the moment that I add the scheduled refreshment, I got the message: 
**you can't schedule refresh because this dataset contains data sources that do not yet support refresh.**

Does anyone see why this didn't work, any help will be really appropriated.

**Answer: I should load directly my data into a data model instead of into a worksheet, now the refreshment works fine!**

---

Now I got another question, I have two tables like below

1. Table devices.

   **deviceid, network_type, location, language**
   id001,wifi,us,english

   id002,gsm,france,french

   id003,wifi,italy,italian.....
2. Table data consuming.

   **deviceid, volume_consuming, date**

   id001, 200, 04-03-2015

   id001,300, 04-05-2015

   id002,500, 04-06-2015

   id002, 600, 04-05-2015

   id003,800, 04-03-2015

   id003, 1000, 04-06-2015

I need to calculate average data consuming per device and aggregate by date, then I created this table below

3. Table aggregation by date

   **date, avg_data_per_device**

   04-03-2015,  500

   04-05-2015,  450

   04-06-2015,  750

Now comes my question, I want to add some filter to my graph which is based on the third table, since there are no deviceid in this table(it's an aggregation table), can I do some manipulation under PowerBI to acheive this, does anyone have any ideas please, thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two common issues you might be hitting. First, to use SQL Azure in Excel workbooks with refresh, you'll need to use the Power Query UI to build the query (if you specify a custom query it won't work).  Second, if you have other queries that load data from excel worksheets it won't work either.  Would suggest pairing down your queries until you have just one for SQL Azure. If that all doesn't fix the issue, then you should use the "Contact Support" feature in the Power BI UI that's under the question mark icon.

Appreciate your using Power BI,
-Lukasz

- http://dev.powerbi.com
- http://blogs.msdn.com/powerbidev
- Make a feature request: https://support.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi
- Sign up for Power BI: http://www.powerbi.com

Comment: Hello @Lukasz, you are right, I do hit the 2e issue that you talked below, thanks for your help! I've been switching from Tableau to PowerBI recently, there are quite a lot differences between these 2 tools

Comment: Great to hear it worked for you.  Wanted to give you a gentle nudge to vote up the answer so others know it solved your problem. Thanks!